# syncfusion license flutter SfDateRangePicker

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I used the SfDateRangePickerin my application but this display message syncfusion license.why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWEDz.png)

Comment: How i can access without license???

Comment: Can you provide the code so we can see what may be causing that? And that message might be appearing because you might be using a paid feature, and therefore the library detects that you do not have a valid lincense.

Comment: don't make it a comment. Edit your question and format the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
     import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';  

     child: SfDateRangePicker(
     view: DateRangePickerView.month,
    minDate:_minDate , 
    maxDate: _maxDate, 
    selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.single, 
    controller: _datePickerController, 
    startRangeSelectionColor: Colors.grey,
   endRangeSelectionColor: Colors.grey, 
   rangeSelectionColor: Colors.black12,
  rangeTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20), 
  monthViewSettings: DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(specialDates: <DateTime>[ 
  DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)), DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)), ]), 
  ]), onSelectionChanged: selectionChanged,
  monthCellStyle: DateRangePickerMonthCellStyle(
          specialDatesDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
        shape: BoxShape.circle),
    blackoutDateTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decoration: 
      TextDecoration.lineThrough),
    specialDatesTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),

),
```